# Android class data disappears if app is in the background for too long

Tags: android

I have an Android app that has a class that stores a reference to several entity classes. This class works well but with one issue.

If I have data in this class and then move the app to the background (press the home button) and wait long enough and do other things with my phone, when I bring the app to the foreground the data is gone. The app will load to the last opened screen (not restarting the app) but all data that was stored in this class is gone.

It doesn't happen always so I assume it is some sort of memory management issue but I am trying to figure out a way to keep this data persistent or, if it existed and now does not, have the app restart from the beginning.

How can I keep this data / rebuild it?

Comment: Use Sharedpreferences http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) to better understand how and when your activity will be destroyed, created, etc.

Before your activity is destroyed the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` method will be called on it. Override the method to save state to the bundle. Data saved in this manner will be provided to `onCreate(Bundle)` in subsequent calls.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("myKey", "myValue"); // trivial, but for illustration purposes.
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably the best solution (accepted as such). I am guessing my pointer to the class instance is getting knocked off due to memory management. Thus I have to tear the class down in onSaveInstanceState and rebuild it in onCreate (if exists).

Answer (score 1):

U can Save Data in  Bundle object, this object will be passed as a parameter to the Oncreate of activity that you are loading. if The data you are storing is small then you can use sharedpreference and get it back while loading the activity.

My guess is like you might be clearing the object of your entity class in onpause method  of your activity, so you may be loosing out data, just check that once..